# Arcgis JS Api mapping mashup how?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, mashup

I have gis data which i can access over Arcgis Rest with Arcgis js api and i have non-gis data which i get from different db.I want to mashup this two like in this link

http://www.cartographicperspectives.org/index.php/journal/article/viewFile/cp76-hunt/1311  (look page 6)

this is my code

```
DemMin = new Number; DemMax = new Number; 
jQuery("#testMenu").click(function () {
// sample -- > is feature layer already defined somewhere else in the code

    $.getJSON('/home/getresult', null,  // this returns array of json like [{grid_no= 2,avg_heat=3},{grid_no= 1,avg_heat=5}]
function (data) {
   $.each(data, function (i, C) {

       if (C.avg_heat < DemMin) { DemMin = C.avg_heat; }
       if (C.avg_heat > DemMax) { DemMax = C.avg_heat; }

       $.each(sample.graphics, function (k, G) {

           if (G.attributes.GRID_NO == C.grid_no) {
               G.attributes.AVG_HEAT = C.avg_heat;  // (1) adding featurlayer.graphics.attributes not featurelayer field i know ::)),  look for (2)
               alert(G.attributes.AVG_HEAT);   // this alert works and shows G.attributes.AVG_HEAT which i added
               return false;
           }
       });
   });

   var testrenderer = new SimpleRenderer(new SimpleFillSymbol().setOutline(new SimpleLineSymbol().setWidth(0.5)));

   testrenderer.setColorInfo({//set classification values and symbology color information
       field: "AVG_HEAT",   // (2)  This my adding, why i getting error ,this is field not in feature layer i know:))
       minDataValue: DemMin,
       maxDataValue: DemMax,
       colors: [
           new Color([255, 0, 0]),
           new Color([255, 255, 0])]
   });

   sample.setRenderer(testrenderer);

   sample.redraw();

});
```

the error i get of course

--  esri.layers.FeatureLayer: unable to find 'AVG_HEAT' field in the layer 'fields' information  "feature_layer_url"

is there anyway to this code working?

Note : I know Arcgis js api  "Gas price data by state mashup"  sample is similar mashup but please stay on this sample !!

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure the [fields[]](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#fields) array associated with your featureLayer includes any field you'd like to render on.

an alternative example, in which the entire [featureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html) is created from a [featureCollection](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#featurelayer2), and information about the schema of the table is supplied via a layerDefinition, can be found [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/fl_featureCollection.html).